# Video is not displayed in videoview in android?

Tags: android, video

My application uses a simple `VideoView` .It uses an `3gp` file from `assets`but all i can see is a blank screen and music of that video.

Would someone help me to display the `video`?

**P.S-I am trying it on emulator?**

Comment: There has been some problems found in Video playing in Emulator,best way to test **Try on Device** , or use with **Higher version >2.1 Emulator** and yes There are lot many *same question asked on SO* before..no need to repeat it..you can also **SEARCH** on StackOverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Videoview video not seen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855246/android-videoview-video-not-seen)

Comment: may be you have given some background attribute to video view....
actually it was the case with me after removing that background everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Do not use emulator for testing video playback. Its ability to handle video playback is very limited. You should use actual device to play videos.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005928/1341006 by Commonsware for more details